# Variadic functions of multiple-type arguments

Tags: c++, boost, singleton, variadic-functions

I've implemented a templatize singleton interface, here it is a little piece of it:

```
template<class T>
class SingletonObject {
private:
    static boost::shared_ptr<T> instance_ptr;
    static boost::mutex thread_safety_mutex;

    SingletonObject() {}
    ~SingletonObject() {}
    SingletonObject(const SingletonObject&) {}
    void operator=(const SingletonObject&) {}

public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<T> getInstance_ptr() {
        using namespace boost::details::pool;
        guard<boost::mutex> thread_safety_guard(thread_safety_mutex);

        if (!instance_ptr) {
            instance_ptr.reset(new T());
            atexit(singletonMemoryHandler<T>);
        }

        return instance_ptr;
    }
  ...
};

 ...

template<class T>
void singletonMemoryHandler() {
    SingletonObject<T>::destroyInstance();
}
```

So the previous snippet shows implementation of `getInterface_ptr()`. The problem within it is that I can only create `SingletonObject`s with *no arguments*.

Now, I'm looking for a method to pass a different number of parameters having different types.

For example, *singletonizable objects* can be constructed like this:

```
SingletonizableObj1(T1 a1, T2 a2, T3 a3);
SingletonizableObj2(T1 a1, T4 a2, T5 a3, T6 a4);
 ...
```

So that `new T()` could become `new T(T1 a1 ... Tn n)` (maybe this parameters list could be passed within `getInstance_ptr(T1 a1 ... Tn n)`).

Is there a simple way to achieve this goal?

**EDIT1:**
this could be a concrete example:

```
Probe(std::queue<Packet>& recv_pkts, std::queue<Packet>& send_pkts, Sniffer& sniffer);
```

This one is constructing a `Probe` object taking three reference arguments. A way I thought to solve this problem, could be declare for each singletonizable objects an `init` function so `SingletonObject` for the `Probe` (without parameters in the costructor) could be:

```
 ...
// declarations
boost::shared_ptr<Probe> p(SingletonObject<Probe>::getInstance_ptr());
p->init(recv_pkts, send_pkts, sniffer);
 ...
```

But I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Why don't you let the compiler do the heavy-lifting? A static function-scope object will be initialized once, on first encountering it, in a thread-safe manner. Far easier and less error-prone.

Comment: something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d61f2582d1bc9b36) ?

Comment: The sad thing is that you always have to provide the argument to be sure that it will be the correct one you have... A dedicated construct seems better.

Comment: @Jarod42 in a manner (*constructors*) or in another one (*init functions*), parameters always have to be passed.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm trying to write this code only one time: if I had to implement singleton manually for each object, I will be repeating (coping and pasting it into different files) always the same code for each class (excepting for constructor declaration).

Comment: @FilippoLauria: is c++11 an option as [I proposed under this link?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d61f2582d1bc9b36)

Comment: @PiotrS. that could be interesting (even if I'm not using c++11). Now I will do some test.

Comment: What C++ standard are you programming for?

Comment: ehm, you mean gnu++98? Can you upgrade to a moderately modern standard? Anyway, my answer below should work, but you might really need the dummy-argument. (And normal functions instead of template-specializations...)

Comment: Yes, sorry I apologized. From the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/Standards.html#Standards): _The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu++98._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way I found:

```
static boost::shared_ptr<T> getInstance_ptr() {
      ...
    if (!instance_ptr)
        instance_ptr.reset(new T());

    return instance_ptr;
}

template<class T1> static boost::shared_ptr<T> getInstance_ptr(T1& a1) {
     ...
    if (!instance_ptr)
        instance_ptr.reset(new T(a1));

    return instance_ptr;
}

template<class T1, class T2> static boost::shared_ptr<T> getInstance_ptr(
        T1& a1, T2& a2) {
     ...
    if (!instance_ptr)
        instance_ptr.reset(new T(a1, a2));

    return instance_ptr;
}

template<class T1, class T2, class T3> static boost::shared_ptr<T> getInstance_ptr(
        T1& a1, T2& a2, T3& a3) {
     ...
    if (!instance_ptr)
        instance_ptr.reset(new T(a1, a2, a3));

    return instance_ptr;
}

  ...
```

I can't figure out a better solution to achieve my goal. With previous sample code it is shown a *massive overload* of `geInstance_ptr` for a different number of *formal parameters*.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T> T& getSingleton() {static T r; return r;}
```

That's all the singleton-framework you need. Just make all ctors private and `friend` the proper template-instantiation.

Now, if you want to call non-default-ctors, for any of them, just specialize it:

```
template<> Mega& getSingleton<Mega>() {static Mega r(1,2,3,4,5); return r;}
```

The compiler will do the heavy-lifting of initializing it on first use, in a thread-safe way.

If you want to use `std::shared_ptr`s with it, that's easy enough.

If you are okay with it being destroyed at the end, in order of creation, use a non-owning shared-pointer, like this:

```
template<class T> std::shared_ptr<T> getSharedSingleton()
{ return {std::shared_ptr<T>(), &getSingleton());
```

Side-note: You might have to add a `T* = 0`-argment for compatibility with old compilers.

Comment: OP wants to use a non default constructor :-/

Comment: @Jarod42: Added a bit how he can, for select cases.